# Download each tab of Google Sheet to hard drive as .csv

Tags: csv, google-sheets, tabs

I found this code: [Google spreadsheet: Download all the sheets at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28707169/google-spreadsheet-download-all-the-sheets-at-once/28711961#28711961?newreg=b30fd907b83c482590d982be9e93699b) which downloads every tab in a Google Sheet to Drive; this almost works for me, I need to download to my hard drive as individual .csvs instead of to Drive as .csvs.  Can someone modify this for me?

Comment: I am not sure you can download google drive content to your hard drive using google scripts. See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42947229/google-apps-script-downloading-files-from-drive-same-user

Comment: You would have to deploy it as a web app if you want to download files to you hard drive, doing [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17460815/10612011). The problem with this, though is that only one file can be downloaded at a time, so you would have to either (1) implement some UI to download the different files one by one, or (2) add all files in a zip file and download the zip file. Could any of these two workarounds be appropriate for you? If that's the case, I'd post an answer explaining this in more detail.

Comment: Thank you Rann and Lamblichus.  I am trying to get around needing to download each file individually as I am doing that manually today.  I often have worksheets with 70+ tabs so this is very tedious.  I need the files individually to upload them into a program.  If they can be downloaded as individual files into a zip file, that would be fine, assuming I could just unzip the file on my hard drive and upload each file as necessary.